# I am not receiving correctly my signals with SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2

Tags: c, server, signals, pid

I've got a problem while using `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2` signals. Actually I have a client program that send a string `*str` in binary (eg: `1100111` for g letter) to a server program, by using `SIGUSR1` signal for the '1' and `SIGUSR2` for the '2'. The server receive them like that :

```
signal(SIGUSR1, my_handler);
signal(SIGUSR2, my_handler);
pause();
```

where my_handler correspond to :

```
void my_handler(int signum) {
if (signum == SIGUSR1)
    printf("1");
else
    printf("0"); }
```

But the problem is that the output for the 'g' character for exemple is `01` so it seems that the reception is not correct. What should I do to print `1100111` from my server ?
Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]" to learn how this site works. Then come back and [edit] your question, providing [example]s of both your client and your server. -- Are you aware that the handler is reset to its default when handled, at least in many systems? -- `signal()` is deprecated, see its documentation for further information. -- `printf()` is not safe to be called in a signal handler.

Comment: Signals aren't queued so if your program gets another sigusr1 before it can handle the first one you'll have data loss...

Comment: @Shawn is there any alternative then?

Comment: @antiyro to communicate between a client and a server on the same computer? Unix sockets are commonly used

Answer (score 0):

> Signals aren't queued

Typically, standard signals aren't, but real-time signals are, so those are an alternative. But there are two other problems with using two (or more) signals for your purpose:

1. A signal can interrupt the handling of another signal; this can be solved by blocking both (or more) during the signal handling.
2. Even though real-time signals are queued (which achieves that as many signals are received as were sent), this does not achieve that different signals are delivered to the handler in the order in which they were sent; that problem remains.

So, to get rid of the second problem, we must use only one signal. (This also makes the first problem disappear, because the one signal is automatically blocked during its handling.) Of course this means we need another means of passing the information you want to send. Fortunately there is [`sigqueue()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigqueue.html) which sends a *value* along with the signal. In order to access this value in the signal handler, we must install that with [`sigaction()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) rather than with `signal()`. This way, the relevant parts of your *server program* become

```
void my_handler(int signum, siginfo_t *info, void *uc)
{
    write(1, &(char){'0'+info->si_value.sival_int}, 1);
}

…
    struct sigaction act = { .sa_sigaction = my_handler,
                             .sa_flags     = SA_SIGINFO };
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGRTMIN, &act, NULL);
    for (; ; ) pause();
```

and the *client program* sends the example pattern with the sequence

```
    sigqueue(pid, SIGRTMIN, (union sigval){1});
    sigqueue(pid, SIGRTMIN, (union sigval){1});
    sigqueue(pid, SIGRTMIN, (union sigval){0});
    sigqueue(pid, SIGRTMIN, (union sigval){0});
    sigqueue(pid, SIGRTMIN, (union sigval){1});
    sigqueue(pid, SIGRTMIN, (union sigval){1});
    sigqueue(pid, SIGRTMIN, (union sigval){1});
```